# ios distribution certificate: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I unfortunately removed the ios distribution certificate of my application. I want to create an other one but have the error when I build my app: App installation failed: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

Here is my process to create a provisioning profile:

1. Request certificate:

   - In keychain access, I Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Request a Certificate From a Certificate Authority.
   - Enter the e-mail address and name of my apple developer account, save the CertficateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest.
2. Create ios production certificate:

   - in https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/, I add a production App store and Ad hoc certificate.
   - I use the CertficateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest of the first step and generate the certificate.
3. Create distribution provisioning profile

   - In provisioning profile, I add App store distribution provisioning profile.
   - Continue and select my App ID, then my production certificate generated in step 2.
   - I set the name as 'myapp distribution'.
4. Set provisioning profile in Xcode

   - In Xcode, I download the provisioning profile in Xcode > preferences  then choose Team Name, click view Details and download my new provisioning profile.
   - In Xcode left view, I choose my project > build settings > Code Signing and set "Don't Code sign" for each Code Signing Identity.
   - For TARGETS, Code signing identity for debug is iPhone Developer:'my app ID' (Debug and any iOS SDK) and for Release iPhone Distribution:'My app ID' (Release Any iOS SDK). The provisioning Profile for Debug is my App development (Development provisioning profile) and for Release my App distribution (Distribution provisioning profile).

Then, when I build and run with release mode in my iphone, I have this error: 
App installation failed: A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.

I think that my iphone is not linked with the production provisioning profile, Nevertheless it is registered in my developer account.

Comment: This probably goes without saying, but if you have your developer account linked with your Xcode project... you can just go to your Target and click "Fix Issue" and it will create a provisioning profile for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When Xcode creates a provisioning profile for me, it creates a development provisioning profile while I want a distribution provisioning profile. Is it normal ?

Comment: I can usually just distribute to the App Store with the provisioning profile auto generated through Xcode, unless I have some features that need a provisioning profile created manually, such as remote push notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the last hint, I would suggest you try the following:

1. In Apple's Member-Center, go to "Certificates, Identifiers and Profiles", and under "iOS Apps" choose "Devices"
2. Make sure your device is listed.
3. Go to the section "Provisioning Profiles" -> "Distribution", click the Ad-Hoc profile and then click "Edit".
4. In the "Certificates" section, make sure that the distribution certificate is checked.
5. In the "Devices" section, make sure that your device is checked.
6. Click "Generate", re-download and re-build.

good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your solution seems to work. The problem was that I had created an App store certificate while the one I needed was the Ad-Hoc profile. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I did reset all certificate and provisioning, but no luck.

Then I realized my phone's date time was wrong, the year is 2017. Then I reset date time setting. Build it again and everything works.

So, check your phone's date time setting.